# CSV utf8 import with phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, csv, utf-8, phpmyadmin

I am trying to import a dataset with korean characters in, saved as unicode encoding using CSV LOAD DATA

even when I set the input character set to utf8 the korean get's mangled

the encoding for that column is of course utf8

sample record (tab delimited):

```
79  읽다  read    NULL
```

what goes into MYSQL:

```
79  ì½ë‹¤   read    NULL
```

Comment: Please post a sample record and what gets into the database.

Comment: How are you importing the file?

Comment: CSV using LOAD DATA 
\t to represent tabs

can I attach a screenshot?

Comment: apparent I cant upload images yet, I'm using phpmyadmin import

Comment: Don't you have a character set drop-down menu when using phpMyAdmin's import function?

Comment: yes and I set it to UTF8 right at the bottom of the list, I created the csv file in notepad and saved it as UTF8 encoded, I have tried with unicode too and produces similar results

Comment: the collation for the korean field is utf8_unicode_ci

Comment: Strange. When you look into the dump file, you are seeing the correct characters?

Comment: the csv data file I created with notepad is fine yeah, even goes into excel fine

Comment: if I do an export from phpmyadmin I see the same as I see browsing the db: the Korean that I input manually is fine but the imported stuff is mangled

Comment: Really strange. I have no other idea except to play around with the incoming encoding, maybe another one does the trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

load data supports character set clause

```
load data local infile 'filename.txt' into table test.unicode CHARACTER SET utf8
```

Use it from the command line if phpmyadmin ignores it.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like phpmyadmin ignores the select drop-down, and does not append the CHARACTER SET utf8 clause to the query.

You can manually execute the query that phpMyAdmin should, however. Try this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'e:\\www\\wro11.csv' INTO TABLE `videos` CHARACTER SET utf8 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

**here is an example:**
    LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.txt' INTO TABLE tbl_name
      FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
      LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
      IGNORE 1 LINES;

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html