# importing CSV excel to phpmyadmin then "?" is introduced automatically

Tags: excel, csv, phpmyadmin, localhost

There is CSV excel file having data of names with some special characters etc like "á" , when it is imported to localhost's phpmyadmin, then in some data "?" is introduced automatically in data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you have a **[charset-encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/character-encoding) issue**... `UTF-8` instead of `ISO-something`.

Try the below from [CSV utf8 import with phpmyadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539996/csv-utf8-import-with-phpmyadmin)

```
load data local infile 'filename.txt' into table test.unicode CHARACTER SET utf8
```

... or try to adapt it to your needs we barely can guess from your question ;)